# How to use GradientBoostingClassifier init Parameters in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to use one sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier to **init** another sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier, but it raises error "IndexError: too many indices for array". It seams that it's an error in sklearn and also I've found pull request in [sklearn on GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/5221) and [sklearn on GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2691). If someone try to do this and have positive experience please let me know.

**System info:**
MacOS X 10.11.5 (15F34)
python -V : Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)
sklearn.__version__ : '0.17.1'

Above is a sample code that shows this error.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
X, y = X[y < 2], y[y < 2]  # make it binary

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

# Fit GBT init with RF
clf = ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf2 = ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier(init=clf)

clf2.fit(X_train, y_train)
acc = clf2.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Accuracy: {:.4f}".format(acc2))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454139/gradientboostingclassifier-with-a-baseestimator-in-scikit-learn